# Help adding variable to existing apex class

Tags: apex

I have an apex class that reviews the last five opportunities relating to an account and averages out the frequency in days between those five opportunities. Various variables are already being leveraged. I need to include the variable "Amount > 0". My apex class code is below. Can anyone help me do this?

```
public with sharing class OpportunityTriggerHandler {
public static void orderFrequencyValue(Boolean isAfter, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isDelete, List<Opportunity> newLst, Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap, List<Opportunity> oldLst){
    if(isAfter){
        list<Id> accId = new list<Id>();
        if(isInsert){
            for(Opportunity o : newLst){
                if(o.IsWon)
                    accId.add(o.accountId); 
            }
        }
        if(isUpdate){
            for(Opportunity o : newLst){
                if(o.IsWon && (!oldMap.get(o.id).IsWon || o.CloseDate != oldMap.get(o.id).CloseDate))
                    accId.add(o.accountId); 
                if (!o.IsWon && oldMap.get(o.id).IsWon)
                    accId.add(o.accountId);
            }   
        }
        if(isDelete){
            for(Opportunity o : oldLst){
                if(o.IsWon)
                    accId.add(o.accountId); 
            }
        }
        if(accId.size()>0){
            List<Opportunity> lstOpps = [Select o.IsWon, o.IsClosed, o.Id, o.CloseDate, o.AccountId 
                                           From Opportunity o 
                                          where o.IsWon = true and o.AccountId in:accId order by o.CloseDate desc];
            integer days = 0;
            integer i;
            Map<String,List<Opportunity>> accIdOpp = new Map<String,List<Opportunity>>();
            List<Opportunity> latestOpps;
            for(Opportunity o : lstOpps){
                if(accIdOpp.containsKey(o.AccountId)){
                    latestOpps = accIdOpp.get(o.AccountId);
                    latestOpps.add(o);
                    accIdOpp.put(o.AccountId,latestOpps);
                }else{
                    latestOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
                    latestOpps.add(o);
                    accIdOpp.put(o.AccountId,latestOpps);
                }
            }
            List<Opportunity> tempList;
            Map<String,Integer> accIdDays = new Map<String,Integer>();
            for(String acc : accIdOpp.keySet()){
                days=0;
                for(i=0; i<accIdOpp.get(acc).size()-1 && i<5;i++){
                    tempList = accIdOpp.get(acc);
                    //system.debug(tempList[i+1].CloseDate.daysBetween(tempList[i].CloseDate) + 'srikar1');
                    days = days + tempList[i+1].CloseDate.daysBetween(tempList[i].CloseDate);
                }

                system.debug(accIdOpp.get(acc).size() + 'no of accs' + i + 'number of records');
                if(days!=0){
                    if(i>0)                     
                        accIdDays.put(acc,Math.round(days/i));                      
                }
            }
            if(accIdDays.size()>0){
                List<Account> lstAccs = [Select a.Order_Frequency_in_Days__c, a.Id From Account a where a.Id in:accIdDays.keySet()];
                for(Account a: lstAccs){
                    a.Order_Frequency_in_Days__c = accIdDays.get(a.Id);
                    system.debug(a.Order_Frequency_in_Days__c  + 'Frequency of days');
                }               
                update lstAccs;
            }
        }   
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when do you want to use the amount variable? where do you want to include the variable in the above logic?  need more information

Comment: You can't. The "Amount > 0" is an expression that results in a value that is assigned to a variable or evaluated. It itself cannot be a variable. (All in good fun). We need more information to help you with this.

Comment: I want to use the Amount variable in all instances of evaluation (after an opp is completed, updated, or deleted; if deleted, remove opp entry from evaluation). Our business is transaction intensive and we use the opp object for order entries. Based on an Acct's past behavior, we use this apex class to get insight into an Acct's future behavior. If an order needs to be replaced for whatever reason, an opp is entered at an Amount value of "0". These "0" value opps distort the outcome of this apex classes evaluation. I need to remove them or only evaluate opps with Amounts > "0".

Answer (score 0):

Modify your SOQL, add another criteria block 'AND Amount > 0' to your opportunity list like so:

```
List<Opportunity> lstOpps = [Select o.IsWon, o.IsClosed, o.Id, o.CloseDate, o.AccountId From Opportunity o where o.IsWon = true and o.AccountId in:accId and o.Amount > 0 order by o.CloseDate desc];
```

Comment: Hey Uber, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work :(

Comment: I tried this in my sandbox and it does "work" provided your requirement is what you stated, namely, to only include Opportunity records in this calculation if their Amount > 0. Which specific scenario are you testing? Update/Create/Delete? Please provide more details so we can debug what is going on.